# Swift Networking & Response Serialization

Tags: ios, swift, swift-protocols

I want to implement Generic parsers in Swift. I cannot use Codable as most of the models are in Objective C. Is there a protocol-oriented way to convert the response data directly into Models with Codable?

Comment: I am looking for a generic solution.